# How do I add an Excerpt box to custom post types in functions?

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress-3.9

I just want the standard Excerpt box - not a metabox of my own creation, added to a Custom Post.  The box shows up in Posts but not in Custom Posts.  I've tried both of these older solutions but neither of them worked (maybe it's a WP 3.9 problem):

The custom post type name is "Scoop"

I added this to the `register_post_type_scoop() $labels = array`

```
'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','excerpt')
```

but it didn't work - neither did this:

```
add_post_type_support('Scoop', 'title');
add_post_type_support('Scoop', array('title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt') );
```

Comment: I found the answer with this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rich-text-excerpts/installation/

and this code in functions adds excerpts to the named Custom Post type:

`add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');
function my_custom_init() {
 add_post_type_support( 'scoop', 'excerpt' );
}`

I knew it would be simple - just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a index value `excerpt` to the `supports` object. Below the example is:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_testimonial_posttype' );
function create_testimonial_posttype(){
  register_post_type( 'testimonials',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Testimonials' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Testimonial' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'clients'),
      'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','editor','page-attributes','excerpt'),
    )
  );
}
```